# Strange crash of Qt 4.8.4 QList under Apple LLVM

Tags: c++, macos, qt, llvm-clang, qlist

Does anybody know why this code crashes?

Code that crashes:

```
QList<int> lst;
const auto& tmp = QList<int>() << 1;
lst = tmp;
```

Code that works (tmp is not a reference):

```
QList<int> lst;
const auto tmp = QList<int>() << 1;
lst = tmp;
```

Compiler:

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Crash message:

```
qt_test(76726,0x7fff76257180) malloc: *** error for object 0x101208b60: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
qt_test: line 43: 76726 Abort trap: 6           $DBG_TEST "$@"
```

This message appears when 'lst' destructor called.

Under VisualStudio 2012 this code works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this more, I finally noticed the glaring inconsistency.

```
QList<int> lst;
const auto& tmp = QList<int>() << 1;
lst = tmp;
```

Specifically, looking at this line:

```
const auto& tmp = QList<int>() << 1;
```

`QList<int>()` is a temporary. This temporary is being passed into `QList<int>::operator<<(...)`, which is then returning it back as a reference. The problem here is the level of indirection; if you tried to store `QList<int>()` into a const-reference, it should live until the const-reference fell out of scope. But that reference was instead passed to an operator as `this`, and is lost by the end of the statement.

Why this works in Visual Studio and not GCC is questionable. A quick Google for answers turns up at least one [interesting result](http://askldjd.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/const-reference-to-temporary-is-useless/) where it points to the following clauses in the standard:

> If the initializer expression is an rvalue, with T2 a class type, and “cv1 T1″ is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” the reference is bound in one of the following ways (the choice is implementation defined):
>
> The reference is bound to the object represented by the rvalue or to a subobject with that object
>
> A temporary of type “cv1 T2″ is created, and a constructor is called to copy the entire rvalue object into the temporary. This reference is bound to the temporary or to a subobject with the temporary.

So, it looks like Visual Studio is taking the second approach, which happens to make a difference in this edge case, since the value will be copied in the statement anyways. It really does put into question the usefulness of a const-reference, though.

Comment: Yes, I thought so at first. I tried to reproduce problem using MyClass instead of QList<>. I have noticed that compiler makes a copy of MyClass before assigning to 'tmp'. Because tmp is a const reference it should keep that copy alive. Currently I guess that problem is in QList<> and Qt's implicit sharing. 
If you sure that there is undefined behaviour in my code, please point me to description in c++ standard.

Comment: Actually, I forgot about that feature of C++. But my point stands, because you are storing the value returned by `QList<int>::operator<<(...)`, not the temporary itself - whether they're the same or not. There is no possible way the compiler could know that `operator<<(...)` is returning the temporary you passed in.

Comment: Updated my answer, with what I hope gives a fuller picture of the issue. Much more interesting edge case than I initially had pictured.

Comment: Thank you John! I suppose that this is actually undefined behaviour. Destructor of the temporary object is called earlier than assignment operator. You may see output here http://ideone.com/JywwRB